# how the upload form in web browser can open many complete action such as gallery and native camera in android

Tags: android, forms, upload

Hello i'm making image upload form in web browser android, but i need the form can use native camera and show gallery option in complete action android, can anyone help me?
i have my code like this...but it only show the camera, i need the gallery too.

```
<form:form id="myformid" class="form_upload" modelAttribute="uploadItem"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<form:input path="data" id="myid" class="form_up_att uploadpic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" type="file" />
</form:form>
```

Thank you.